# Oracle bound variables

Tags: oracle, variables, binding

I'm new to working with bound variables, so I've got a small question - 
I'm using an Oracle DB and ODP.NET in a .NET app, and I'm using bound variables like this

```
string sql = "select * from table1 where loc=:pLoc and pno=:pPno and sno=:pSno union all select * from table2 where loc=:pLoc and pno=:pPno and sno=:pSno union all 
select * from table3 where loc=:pLoc and pno=:pPno and sno=:pSno";

    OracleCommand _cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, DBFacade.DbConnection);

                    OracleParameter pLoc = new OracleParameter(":pLoc", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 3);
                    pLoc.Value = loc;
                    OracleParameter pSno = new OracleParameter(":pSno", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10);
                    pLoc.Value = sno;
                    OracleParameter pPno = new OracleParameter(":pPno", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 18);
                    pLoc.Value = pno;

                    _cmd.Parameters.Add(pLoc);
                    _cmd.Parameters.Add(pSno);
                    _cmd.Parameters.Add(pPno);

                    _odaContractPrices.SelectCommand = _cmd;
```

I've used bound variables successfully in other sql statements (in simpler queries like "select * from table1 where column1=:param1 and column2=:param2"), but for some reason in this one it doesn't work. Can anyone explain me why ? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What are the symptoms?

Comment: I use that adapter to fill a dataset. By "doesn't work" i mean the dataset it's empty.

Comment: `OracleCommand _cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, loc, sno, pno), DBFacade.DbConnection);` can't even compile.

Comment: my bad ( copy paste error ) it was :  OracleCommand _cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, DBFacade.DbConnection);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the source of the error but try to remove the : in the OracleParameter constructor and use

```
_cmd.BindByName = true;
```

Actually, I think that in your case, the following will suffice:

```
_cmd.Parameters.Add("pLoc", loc);
_cmd.Parameters.Add("pSno", sno);
_cmd.Parameters.Add("pPno ", pno);
```

Comment: @maephisto just to add some comment, ODP binds by order by default "ODP.NET lets you use two modes with bind variables: bind by position (the default) or bind by name" [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-sep/o55odpnet-101704.html] this can cause a good amount of confusion